# Posting empty results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to make a trade script were users can trade each others monsters.
So i have a script were it shows there monsters and the users monsters that they type in so if the user types in nick it will shows the pokemon nick monsters and the user who typed it in monster.
All of whic works fine it displays what i want.
Now i want to store the monsters they want and are offering in the db.  And that is were we come to the problem. For some resosn its storing the username and the username of the trader ok but not the monsters. Its storing

{"pokemon":[""]}
For the trade_pokeid   and the trade_mypokeid

Here is how i display there monsters and the users monsters which works fine

```
Trade with </h4>
   <?php



$username_trade = $_POST['username_trade'];



$_SESSION['username_trade'] = $username_trade ;

echo "You put in id  ". $username_trade . ".<br />";



?>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><span class="mid_box">
  <?php
                        // get and display userbox
                        $q = "SELECT id,pokemon,exp,level FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION['username_trade']."'";
                        $r = mysql_query($q);

                        if (mysql_num_rows($r) <= 0) {
                            echo "You have no current pokemon stored";

                        }
                    ?>

</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>
  <?php
 echo "<form action='test_process.php' method='POST'>";
while ( $v = mysql_fetch_object( $r ) )
{
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='pokemon[]' value='$v->dbid'/> They have a $v->pokemon    </label><br/>";
        echo "<label> Level $v->level     </label><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='user' value='$username_trade'/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Check!!'/>";
?>
</p>
<p><strong>Pick what you want two offer for the pokemon </strong></p>
<p>
  <?php
                        // get and display userbox
                        $q = "SELECT id,pokemon,exp,level FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='". $_SESSION['username']."'";
                        $t = mysql_query($q);

                        if (mysql_num_rows($t) <= 0) {
                            echo "You have no current pokemon stored";

                        }
                    ?>
</p>
<p>


  <?php
 echo "<form action='test_process.php' method='POST'>";
while ( $v = mysql_fetch_object( $t ) )
{
    echo "<label><input type='checkbox' name='pokemonin[]' value='$v->dbid'/> I have a $v->pokemon</label><br/>";
    echo "<label> Level $v->level     </label><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='hidden' name='userin' value='$username'/>";
echo "</form>";
?>

                <p align="center">
```

Now here is how i try and store them.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$pokemon = $_POST['pokemon'];
$pokemonin = $_POST['pokemonin'];
$meid = $_SESSION['username'];
$toid = $_POST['user'];
$dbid = array();
$dbid2 = array();

foreach ( $pokemon as $poke )
{   $dbid['pokemon'][] = $poke;

}

foreach ( $pokemonin as $poke2 )
{   $dbid2['pokemonin'][] = $poke2;


}




srand ((double) microtime( )*1000000);
$random_number = rand( );
echo "$random_number";


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO trade (trade_id, trade_to, trade_from, trade_pokeid, trade_mypokeid)
                            VALUES ('$random_number','$toid', '$meid', '"$dbid."', '".$dbid2."');") or die("Error: ". mysql_error());






?>
```

What am i doing wrong ? why are the results not being stored ? or carried over the db connect and session start are in the config.php page

Comment: any warnings, notices? have you tried to trace(var_dump) the passed variables? have you checked how the generated SQL query looks like?

Comment: Sidenote: You've got some serious SQL injection vulnerabilities in that code.

Comment: You can't store arrays in mysql! http://www.evolt.org/node/60222

Comment: There is no errors or anything and i only want to get the script working i can make the script safe after. The script was working be for but then chose to start and code again.

Comment: you want to make the script safe while you're writing it. that way there's less chance of forgetting things.

Comment: if you don't see any error display is because it's disabled. check web server log and enable reporting.

Comment: Error reporting is on. Even have put it on the page. The error reporting code to turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

In your last MySQL query, you're trying to insert a PHP array as a string into a query, that won't work. If I'm guessing correctly, you'll want to use something like `implode(",",$dbid['pokemon'])` instead of `$dbid`.

Also, it's definitely a good idea to run mysql_real_escape_string on anything that comes from the user and/or the URL before you put it in a query!

Comment: it depends. an extra table would be better. but the poster wants to insert the entire array into the field, and I can't think of any other convenient way to store multiple integer values inside a single field.

Comment: Well how would you do it ??? If there are 10 monsters they chose they want then the user picks 20 of there monsters they will give for it.   How would you store that ?

Comment: I would make a "trade" table with three fields: tradeId, userOne (who initiated the trade), userTwo. Then I would make a trademonster table with three fields: tradeId, userId, monster. So when user 1 with id 45 wants to trade with user 2 with id 67, you insert a trade row, and get the trade id (let's say 89) back from MySQL with `mysql_insert_id`. Then for each monster of user 1, you insert a row `(89, 45, {$monster})` and for user 2, a row `(89, 67, {$monster})` into the trademonster table. You could add a datetime field and a field indicating whether the trade is done, to the trade table.

Comment: Then, when both parties say the trade is good, you make the field that the trade is done reflect that, (for instance by setting it to 1) and update both users' monster inventories. You can keep the other rows so you can have a history of who traded which monsters with whom.

Comment: Hang on, @yi_H is right. You want implode(). :) _edit: edited my post to say implode and +1'd yi_H's comment_

Answer (score 1):

Your code is open for **sql injection** !
You shuld aviod passing parameters (without escaping) to sql query => for start check:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @user1008843: you should get a -100 for that comment.

Comment: @user1008843 Someone just pointed a very sincere problem in your code out to you and that's how you thank him? You should care about the SQL injection, otherwise someone might be able to break into your system and delete data.

Comment: Im not being nasty but its only my local host . Who is gonna sql attack it ??? LOL I have not asked for sql support. And real sick of people telling me about sql injection when the script is not even live. The problem is not sql injection. And sql injection is not stopping the script from working.

Comment: @user1008843 maybe not stop your scrip from running, but if you publish it => and forget to refator all 'parts like this'. Someone could 'stop' your whole page from running ;) That was my point, localhost or not you shuld write code in right way.

Comment: @user1008843 Say what you want, your code is broken and vulnerable. If you bring your car to the garage to change the tires and they tell you that your brakes do not work, you shold thank them.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error (not enough - or too many dots) in your MYSQL statement...

```
VALUES ('$random_number','$toid', '$meid', '"$dbid."', '".$dbid2."')
```

Should read

```
VALUES ('$random_number','$toid', '$meid', '$dbid', '$dbid2')
```

Comment: getting a white page with your code your missing a "" between the ()  ?